# d-flex removing space from before hyperlink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working hard on my first project, I'm using d-flex along with justify-content-center to center a div as that's what's said in the manual for [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/), I'm having a small issue in the styling that when the page is rendered d-flex seems to be removing a space from before a hyperlink, but when I view the page source the space is there.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">Msg <a href="#">link</a></div>
```

In the render view it looks like "Msglink", but when I view the source it looks correct, "Msg link", I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, if someone could guide me in the right direction it would be much appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: while flexbox is good, it shouldn't be use automatically everywhere ... it's not suitable to make a text wrapper a flex container, you *kill* all the needed whitespace

Comment: thank you very much, i appreciate the response.